# How do I access and iterate array items by index in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I need to iterate the JSON data in the handlebars in {{#each}} statement.

This is the JSON data,

```
{
    "no": 0,
    "address": "Here",
    "name": "There",
    "members": [
    {
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "name": "SH",
        "sex": "F"
    },
    {
        "email": "test2@test.com",
        "name": "SH2",
        "sex": "F"
    }],
    "diary": [
    {
        "ddate":"0820",
        "dcheck":"y"
    },
    {
        "ddate":"0821",
        "dcheck":"n"
    }]
}
```

and this is the Handlebars code.

I need to iterate 1st, 2nd, 3rd... object's properties in the members list.

I want to know what to put in instead of [0].

```
{{#each list}}
<tr>
    <td><a href='bd-view.html?email={{members.[0].email}}'>{{members.[0].email}}</a></td>
    <td>{{members.[0].name}}</td>
    <td>{{members.[0].sex}}</td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{diary.[0].dcheck}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

This is my first question in stackoverflow.

Hope to see someone answer this question.

Thanks a lot, cheers.

Comment: Can you clarify something for me? Are you needing to iterate over each object in your `members` list so that you have three `<td>` elements for each member, one for `email`, `name`, and `sex`, followed by the rest, or are you intending to have one `<tr>` for each `members`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
{{#each members}}
<tr>
    <td><a href='bd-view.html?email={{email}}'>{{email}}</a></td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{sex}}</td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    {{#with (lookup ../diary @index)}}
    <td>{{dcheck}}</td>
    {{/with}}    
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Using the [`#each`](https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration) to iterate your array, and the function [`#lookup`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) to access to relative position of the array `diary`

Answer (score 0):

I actually upvoted Matheus answer using the with lookup of the index.   however I did it a different way where I manipulate the data before passing it in.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.members.length; i++) {
  data.members[i].dcheck = data.diary[i].dcheck;
}
```

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/N2b5M/6750/